# dynamic sql count in a variable

Tags: sql, sybase

This query works

```
select @V_COUNT =COUNT(1) from TAB1
```

But I want to pass the table as variable  how to do that in sybase ?

i tried this but didnt work

```
select @V_COUNT ='COUNT(1) from ''||@TMP_TABLE_NAME||'''
select @LL_COUNT =  CONVERT(numeric(30),@V_COUNT)
```

edit:

i did this

```
 SELECT @V_COUNT ='SELECT COUNT(1) from '+ @TABLE_NAME
     execute (@V_COUNT)
     SELECT @LL_COUNT = 'SELECT convert(NUMERIC(6),'||@V_COUNT||')'
```

> Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'NUMERIC' is not
>   allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute that dynamic query, using:

```
CREATE TABLE #Count(x int)
SELECT @sSQL = "INSERT #Count SELECT COUNT(1) from "+ @TMP_TABLE_NAME
execute (@sSQL)
SELECT @V_COUNT = x from #Count
DROP TABLE #Count
SELECT @LL_COUNT = (SELECT convert(NUMERIC(30,4), @V_COUNT))
SELECT @LL_COUNT
```

where `@TMP_TABLE_NAME` might be `SELECT @TMP_TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'` is simple string which you don't need to execute or get result from.

Comment: @Moudiz won't SELECT LL_COUNT = SELECT convert(NUMERIC(6), @V_COUNT)  work

Comment: i didnt understand , if i dont need to execute how to do it then

Comment: Its giving me error `Syntax error during explicit conversion of VARCHAR value 'SELECT COUNT(1) from CTSCARDS_MGT1' to a NUMERIC field` also when running this procedure is select is giving a new window result `SELECT @V_COUNT ='SELECT COUNT(1) from '+ @TMP_TABLE_NAME`

Comment: @Moudiz declare V_COUNT as varchar, afterall we are converting V_COUNT to numeric later on 3rd line